# put a character on edittext while typing

Tags: android

I have an EditText, and I want to use it for input date, I want to make it so when user insert date, my app will automatically add '-' on EditText, so user only need to insert number,
ex;

```
user type: 21   -> device automatically 21-
user type: 01   -> device automatically 21-01-
user type: 2013 -> device automatically 21-01-2013
```

I tried this;

```
edtTxt1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
          int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Integer textlength1 = edtTxt1.getText().length();
          if (textlength1 == 2) {
                edtTxt1.getText().insert(2, "-");
                edtTxt1.setSelection(3);
                /*I also tried this, no luck
                edtTxt1.setSelection(edtTxt1.getText().length());*/
          }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
           int after) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       }
    });
```

result:

```
user type: 21   -> device automatically 21-
user type: 01   -> device automatically 2101-
```

I can't put cursor after '-'

EDIT
I tried @svenoaks answer, I was able to put cursor after '-' but this is what happen:

```
user type: 21   -> device automatically 21-
user type: 0    -> device automatically 21-210
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
edtTxt1.setText(edtTxt1.getText().insert(2, "-"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you know: you can always use DatePicker for getting date input from user.

Assuming you want to print dd-mm-yyyy, try this

```
if(textlength1==2||textlength1==5||textlength1==7)
edtTxt1.setText(edtTxt1.getText().insert(textlength1, "-"));
```

Comment: DatePicker is too big for me, I want to use EditText since it's more suitable for my app

Comment: here improved my answer. Good luck :)

Comment: same thing happen like svenoaks answer, but since it's useful I will up vote your answer, I'll find another way, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try `edtTxt1.setText("....")`